# Issue with join when shaded smooth

Tags: modeling, edges, extrude

I'm new to Blender and am trying to get my head around things and practice what I've learnt. I'm sure I've done something wrong order here, but I'm having an issue:

I modelled a glass with a handle, starting by creating the glass shape from a cylinder. I then extruded the top of the handle out by selecting that face and hitting 'E'. Then, using the spin tool I created the handle loop (spinning down towards where the handle connects near the bottom of the glass). Then I used the Bridge tool to connect the round shape to the bottom of the glass.

For some reason, although the bottom connection between glass and handle looks perfect, the top one looks way too sharp. I can't quite work out what I've done wrong here! Any help would be appreciated.

[image: cup in edit mode]

[image: cup in object mode]

Comment: you should check the normals, remove doubles, check inner faces...

Comment: Ahh. Your comment prompted me to check the inside face and I realised, I probably should have applied my Solidify modifier first?

Comment: no, don't apply the modifier! check if the mesh is correct before!

Comment: The edges are darker on the problematic area. This indicates there is overlapping geometry there. Maybe you tapped "E" twice when first extruding ? Try going into edit mode and selecting all vertices, then go right click > Merge > By distance

Comment: Ahh. I already applied the modifier and it fixed the issue. However, if it's bad workflow, I'll give it another go without applying! I'm just practising so I'll have a few goes.